# curve fitting estimate parameter - inverse square law

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I want to make a plot force vs position (for coulomb's law) and estimate the constant e0.
I have the values of charges , q1=1,q2=1.
I have for example the

```
position=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1];

force=[0.08,0.015,0.013,0.0062,0.0016,0.00519,-0.00159,0.00118,...
    0.0061,0.00155,0.00143];
```

Coulomb is F= (1/4*pi*e0) * q1*q2/r^2.
So, it is in the form:

y=ax^-m  , where a= (q1*q2/4*pi*e0)

I am doing:

```
p=polyfit(-log10(position),log10(force),1);  % I am not sure about  '1' and minus

m=p(1);
a=10^(p(2)); % I am not sure about a 



xp=0.1:0.1:1.1;
yp=a*xp.^(-m);


plot(position,force,'o',xp,yp)

e0=q1*q2/4*pi*a
```

I am not finding a right value for e0.Am I doing something wrong?
The m value should be -2 but I am taking :

> m =
>
> 1.6287 - 0.2008i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons this is wrong. Firstly, you've missed some parentheses out of your definition of Coulomb's law. It should be

```
F = 1/(4*pi*e0) * q1 * q2 * r^-2
```

This means that your final calculation of `e0` should go like

```
a = 10^p(2);
e0 = ((q1 * q2) / (4 * pi)) / a;
```

The other reason this is wrong is that, in fact, the definition of the law is still wrong for your context. You have only positive charges (`q1`, `q2`) there, but clearly the force goes negative at some point. Since you're working in log-space to estimate the parameters, this is not going to work as you will get a complex number out. Your definition of Coulomb's law for your data should be

```
|F| = 1/(4*pi*e0) * |q1 * q2| * r^-2
```

That is, you only have the absolute values. Therefore you should do the fitting using `abs(force)` instead of just `force`.

Comment: :Hello, I saw you edited a couple of times.:).I think I have the correct formula for F and for e0.The thing is if I am doing right the curve fitting (and as I am watching it I think I may have it right..)

Comment: Your formulae are not correct because `(1/4*pi*e0) == (1/4)*pi*e0` when the formula should be `1/(4*pi*e0)`. I checked again and my calculation of `e0` was wrong, but I have corrected it. Just worked through the formulae and I'm pretty confident that that's the correct method, but doesn't give you the normal value of `e0`. Are you sure `q1 = q2 = 1` is correct?

Comment: :Ok!That's it!I missed the parentheses!!Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since a= (q1*q2/4*pi*e0), e0 should be

```
e0=a/(q1*q2/4*pi)
```

Check it.

Comment: :No, I think it's ok as I have it. :).But the code seems right generally?